# CSS Change button color on selection

Tags: html, css

I am new to web pages and i'm creating a simple web site in which I have some page selector buttons.

The web site uses a master page and asp.

I want the button selected to change color when clicked to identify the currently selected page.
The button should change from Pink to Grey basically and stay that way until another button is clicked.

I have tried all the usual options but nothing seems to work, and I know it is my ignorance!

**HTML snippet**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="MailTest.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ropa+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">   
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="header">
                <img src="images/logo.gif" alt="Whamm Logo" />
        </div>
        <div id="wrap2">
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Default.aspx" onclick="this.classname='cClick'" class="button cColour">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="About.aspx" onclick="this.classname='cClick'" class="button cColour">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Services.aspx" onclick="this.classname='cClick'" class="button cColour">OUR SERVICES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Quotes.aspx" onclick="this.classname='cClick'" class="button cColour">REQUEST A QUOTE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Contact.aspx" onclick="this.classname='cClick'" class="button cColour">CONTACT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.mailbigfile.com/whamm" target="_blank" class="button cColour">UPLOAD A FILE</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
                <!-- #BeginEditable "content" -->
                <!-- #EndEditable -->
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="footer">
            <a href="mailto: mail@wham.co.uk" target="_blank">mail@whamm.co.uk 01509 646553</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS snippet**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0,0,0,0;
    font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif;
}
 #wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:10px; 
    width: 800px;
}
 #header 
 {
  width:800px;
  height:145px;
 }
     img 
     {
     max-height:100%;
     -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
     float:right;
     }
 #wrap2 
 {
 clear:both;
 margin:0;
 width:780px;
 }
 #menu
 {
  margin: 0;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
}
 #main {
margin: 0;
    float:right;
    width:580px;
}

ul
   {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    margin-left:5px;
    text-indent:6px;
   } 
h2 
   {
border:o; margin:0;
font-size:20px;
    color:#e5007e;
   }
/* button 
---------------------------------------------- */
.button
{
    display:block;
    width: 130px;
    height:16px;
    line-height:16px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    margin-left:0;
    outline:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:left;
    border: solid 1px #da7c0c;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-decoration:none;

    -webkit-border-radius: .4em; 
    -moz-border-radius: .4em;
    border-radius: .4em;

}
#footer 
{
clear:both;
margin: 0;
}
 #footer a {
    float:right;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#e5007e;
}
.button:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 2px;
}
.button:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:#9c9b9b;
}
.button.selected {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:#9c9b9b;    
}

/* colour */
.cColour {
    color:white;
    background-color:#e5007e;
}
.cColour:hover {
    color:white;
    background-color:green;
}
.cColour:active {
    color:white;
    background-color:#9c9b9b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a quick and easy way. On each page put this script:

*If you want plain Javascript:*

```
<script>
     document.getElementById("buttonID").className += " hover";
</script>
```

*If you want JQuery:*

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#buttonID').addClass('hover');
     });
</script>
```

`hover` is the class you want to apply when the button is selected. Remember to change the buttonID.

Once the page is loaded, it will apply the `hover` class on the respective button.

Comment: OK 50% there. I have used the java script version to get a reference to the element.      <script type="text/javascript">
                    document.getElementById("about").className += "cColour";
                </script>  this links to the item id     <li><a id="about" href="About.aspx" class="button cColour">ABOUT US</a></li>  BUT.... it still does not pick up the correct CSS class attirbute and applies some as yet unidentified style. I have tested this principle by linking a non-existent class ref. any thoughts?

Comment: @Rupert You've `cColour` class already set for the About `anchor` tag. Remove that class from the `anchor` tag and try. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much asap but if you are using templates then I'd use this principle:

1. Create a selected class in your css with the styles you want.
2. On each page set a variable of page_id to whatever the page is eg: page_id="home"
   3 In you nav template on each a tag use an if statement eg: if(page_id="home") print "class=selected"

Something along those lines should do it, I obv don't know asp but the logic is there.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about ASP, but the concept should be the same in any language. The workflow goes something like:

1. Figure out the current URL
2. Compare the current URL with the menu item's URL
3. If they are the same, give this menu item a special class, like "active" or "selected"
   *Your CSS should have a rule for `.active` or `.selected`*

Here's a post that has the right idea:
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?96221-Highlight-Menu-item-of-Current-Page-using-ASP

Taken from this post:

```
function writeMenu()

    dim i,linkclass,pagename,myMenuItems()

    redim myMenuItems(4)

    myMenuItems(0) = Array("First Page","first.asp")
    myMenuItems(1) = Array("Second Page","second.asp")
    myMenuItems(2) = Array("Third Page","third.asp")
    myMenuItems(3) = Array("Fourth Page","fourth.asp")
    myMenuItems(4) = Array("Fifth Page","fifth.asp")

    pagename = getPageName()

    for i = 0 to ubound(myMenuItems)

        if ucase(myMenuItems(i)(1)) = pagename then
            linkclass = " class=""selected"""
        else
            linkclass = " class=""notselected"""
        end if      

        response.write "<a" & linkclass & " href=""" & myMenuItems(i)(1) & """>" & myMenuItems(i)(0) & "</a><br>"

    next

end function

function getPageName()

    dim scriptArr

    scriptArr = split(request.servervariables("script_name"),"/")

    getPageName = ucase(scriptArr(ubound(scriptArr)))

end function
```